# Concatenate from another sheet and keeping two different text colors VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ampersand

Hi Im trying to get a code that can take data from multiple cells from sheet1 and place them in the same cell on sheet2 but the tricky part is keeping the same colors of the text from sheet1.

For example:

```
sheet one 
A1-Roses(red text)
A2-Are Red(blue text)
```

should read on `sheet2`:

```
A1-RosesAre Red (red and blue text respectively)
```

Comment: SO is not free coding service. Show us your efforts and also what you have and what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: Sounds like you could just record a macro while you copy/paste from one sheet to the other and you would have your code written for you.

Comment: Also, what does "Ampersand" mean in your title?

Comment: ampersand to join two cells of data together in the same cell

Comment: You're going to need to get  A1 and A2's font colors and string length, store those in variables, then after you've concatenated your new sentence you'll need to recolor them with `.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=).Font`, etc... No other way of doing this, really...

Comment: You're going to need VBA most likely, as @dwirony points out.  Also, I have edited the title to replace "ampersand" with "concatenate" which is what I believe you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Taking dwirony's suggestion as an example, you can try using the following code:

```
Sub JoinText()
    With ActiveSheet
        .Range("C3").Value = .Range("A1").Value & " " & .Range("A2").Value
        .Range("C3").Characters(Start:=1, Length:=Len(.Range("A1").Value)).Font.Color = _
            .Range("A1").Font.Color
        .Range("C3").Characters(Start:=Len(.Range("A1").Value) + 1, Length:=255).Font.Color = _
            .Range("A2").Font.Color
    End With
End Sub
```